# How The Sony Hack Was Traced, and So Quickly?

Tags: encryption, network

What are the steps that are required to locate a source that have routed their traffic through multiple zombie hosts, spanning multiple networks/carrier/nations?

Comment: https://twitter.com/SwiftOnSecurity/status/546426218489208832

Answer (score 2):

This is a very long rant with many assumptions, hypothetical questions, and rhetorical questions, none of which play in to why this attack was 'traced' to DPRK. I would suggest cutting almost everything, and leaving your core question, 'How The Sony Hack Was Traced, and So Quickly?'. Everything else is filler and unnecessary to answer the question. Furthermore, no complete answer will likely ever be available as not all information regarding the attack is publicly available.

That being said, a cursory google search will tell you that packets related to the attack came from a Hotel in SE Asia. This apparently is the MO of DPRK hackers, and combined with the source code being written in Korean, has led sources to point at DPRK. I won't weigh in on the logic behind this, as I am assuming (hoping) there is more to these accusations than these two facts alone. (Well, those two and DPRKs public condemnation of The Interview, but that is neither here nor there)

Finally, to correct your misconceptions about encryption, encryption only secures data, it does not prevent users from seeing where said data came from, and even then, SSL/TLS only encrypts data while in transit. So if any C&C servers are hardcoded in the malware, all it would take is a static analysis to reveal their IP.

Comment: I red that while it's suspected the DPRK is behind the hack, it's actually unclear which country the hack was launched from. I don't know how this could work. If I find the news article again I'll post it.

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified better... since we'll never know the exact circumstances I was using assumptions in the context of this real world situation to try to get an answer in the context of what happened. I think you overlooked what I wrote. I'm not foolish enough to not know encryption will not protect from knowing what IP made a connection to another IP and on which port, and any header information that may not be encrypted pre-handshake. I was saying just saying it sounds not very feasible to have access to the logs for all the networks to be able to step backwards after the fact.

Comment: Then to be more specific, how would it be possible to know the packets originated from a particular hotel if the traffic was bounced off many different hosts spanning many different networks/carriers/countries? Even if it wasn't encrypted that would mean the investigation had access to all of the logs for every single route to backtrace to the source, correct? So that would either point to very comprehensive logging and cooperation or that agencies already have logs by unconventional means to much or all of the data on a global scale.